# Counting Values In Columns Igonorig AlphaNumeric Values

Tags: python, pandas, count

First post here, I am trying to **find out total count of values** in an excel file. So after importing the file, I need to run a condition which is count all the values except 0 also where it finds 0 make that blank.

```
> df6 = df5.append(df5.ne(0).sum().rename('Final Value'))
```

I tried the above one but not working properly, **It is counting the column name as well, I only need to count the float values.**

Demo DataFrame:

```
              0        1       2       3
ID_REF      1007_s  1053_a  117_at  121_at
GSM95473    0.08277 0.00874 0.00363 0.01877
GSM95474    0.09503 0.00592 0.00352 0
GSM95475    0.08486 0.00678 0.00386 0.01973
GSM95476    0.08105 0.00913 0.00306 0.01801
GSM95477    0.00000 0.00812 0.00428 0
GSM95478    0.07615 0.00777 0.00438 0.01799
GSM95479    0       0.00508 1       0
GSM95480    0.08499 0.00442 0.00298 0.01897
GSM95481    0.08893 0.00734 0.00204 0
```

> ```
>                 0        1       2       3
> ID_REF        1007_s  1053_a  117_at  121_at
> ```

These are **column name** and **index value** which needs to be **ignored** when counting.

The **output** Should be like this after counting:

> Final 8  9   9 5

Comment: Please post a sample of the dataframe and a desired output.  Also I don't really understand what ignoring zero is supposed to do, it's not like it adds anything to the total `sum`

Comment: You aren't really calculating the `sum`, here, you're counting the number of non-zero values, since `df5.ne(0)` will return a boolean mask of your dataframe.

Comment: @user3483203 i have posted the sample data frame.

Comment: @ user3483203 then how do i actually count the total? I actually need to count the non-zero values and leave the zero and alphanumeric ones.

Comment: It looks like you have a multiindex, is that correct?

Comment: yes @user3483203

Comment: I think your multiindex is getting read as the first row

Answer (score 0):

If you just nee the count, but change the values in your dataframe, you could apply a function to each cell in your DataFrame with the `applymap` method. First create a function to check for a float:

```
def floatcheck(value):
    if isinstance(value, float):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Then apply it to your dataframe:

```
df6 = df5.applymap(floatcheck)
```

This will create a dataframe with a 1 if the value is a float and a 0 if not. Then you can apply your `sum` method:

```
df7 = df6.append(df6.sum().rename("Final Value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to **solve** the issue, So here it is:

```
df5 = df4.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(((df4[1:] != 1) & (df4[1:] != 0)).sum()), index=['Final']))

df5.columns = df4.columns

went = df5.to_csv("output3.csv")
```

What i did was i changed the starting index so i didn't count the first row which was alphanumeric and then i just compared it.

Thanks for your response.